# None focusable ComboBoxItem

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working with `ComboBox` elements that often contain very large quantities of data; ~250000 data entries.

This works fine when a `ComboBox` is set up a little like this.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
</ComboBox>
```

However, some custom modifications of the `ComboBox` I am working with require the `ComboBoxItem` elements to not be focusable. I achieved this by using a setter in the `ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle`.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter
                Property="Focusable"
                Value="False" />
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

But there is a problem with this. It works fine until an object has been selected. Then when a user tries to open the `ComboBox` again, it crashes the program.

My question is, how can the `ComboBox` be set up so all its `ComboBoxItem` elements are not focusable, but it does not crash the program.

---

[image: GIF of Problem]

---

**Example Code**

*XAML*

```
<Window x:Class="FocusableTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="450"
        Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform"
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
            <Label Content="Welcome"
                   FontWeight="Bold"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Viewbox>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="1">
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <VirtualizingStackPanel />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                        <Setter
                            Property="Focusable"
                            Value="False" />
                    </Style>
                </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

*C#*

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace FocusableTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 250000; i++)
            {
                Items.Add(GetUniqueKey());
            }
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        private static string GetUniqueKey(int maxSize = 20)
        {
            char[] chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890".ToCharArray();
            byte[] data = new byte[1];
            using (RNGCryptoServiceProvider crypto = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                crypto.GetNonZeroBytes(data);
                data = new byte[maxSize];
                crypto.GetNonZeroBytes(data);
            }
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(maxSize);
            foreach (byte b in data)
            {
                result.Append(chars[b % (chars.Length)]);
            }
            return result.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I might misunderstand your scenario (probably), but something seems utterly and completely wrong for a combobox to have hundreds of thousands of entries. Poor user who has to wade through this vast volume of data when looking for some specific item in the combobox drop-down...

Comment: @elgonzo Thank you for the comment. In reality, this is a custom `ComboBox` with a search field that allows real-time filtering. The amount of data is still probably a poor user design but that is something I cannot change unfortunately.

Comment: With regard to your problem: I don't see an obvious connection between setting `Focusable` to false in the ComboBoxItem style and the crash. Does the crash also happen if you remove this property setter, while keeping your code otherwise completely unchanged? Does the crash also happens if only a few items (three or four...) are in the combobox? Does the crash happen if you don't use virtualization (using just a few items again, just to figure out the reason for the crash; i don't want to suggest this as a solution)? Are you running the program in the debugger?

Comment: I don't see the crash you describe. When I tried your code I couldn't drop the combobox down again once selected. That's because you set it so it's not focusable... so you can't click the thing.  I think your problem is to do with something else and you should be looking to fix that in a different way.

Comment: @elgonzo The crash does not happen if this piece of code is not there (first code extract in question works fine with 250000 items). The crash also does not happen if there were 5 only non focusable items. The crash happens in both debug and release mode (with 250000 items)

Comment: @Andy The focusable does not prevent me from changing the selection in the `ComboBox`. This can be seen if you were to set the loop to only generate 5 items instead of 250000. Please see the GIF attached in the questions edit of the problem

Comment: From your animated GIF it looks like your program is freezing/locking up instead of crashing. Run your program in the debugger (using debug build). When the freeze occurs, inspect the state of the threads in your program (with special attention to the main/GUI thread). Check what code they were executing or for which resource/wait handle/whatever they were waiting when you paused the program in the debugger.

Comment: Also, in the task manager you can quickly verify if your frozen program is busy (i.e. it is "hung up" doing something), or whether it doesn't consume any CPU cycles (which would indicate that it is dead-locked somewhere somehow)

Comment: Hmm, perhaps also worth as a test to replace `ComboBox` with `ItemsControl`, to determine if the issue is specifically with ComboBox or rather more generally with ItemsControl...

Comment: @elgonzo That is a good idea. I am currently waiting for a performance profiler report to load to see if I can see why it is hanging

Comment: If the debugging and troubleshooting is not bringing you closer to solve the problem, would making the focus visually invisible be sufficient? (The focus would technically be still there and function as such, it would just be invisible/transparent)

Comment: @elgonzo I'm afraid not as the focus being removed is done to resolve an issue that is not just cosmetics. When the mouse hovers over an item, it gets focus. This steals focus from a text box within the combobox which is undesirable

Comment: Okay, i got a chance to test this myself. It is the Selector/Combobox doing something weird. It will eventually open the drop-down, but setting the ComboBoxItems to non-focusable causes WPF to go in circles for a rather long time. Would it be acceptable for your usage scenario to track the (last) UI element that lost the focus, and when the drop-down of the combobox closes (ComboBox.DropDownClosed event) setting the focus back to the element that had the focus before?

Comment: (Note that normally clicking on another UI element when the drop-down is open would close the drop-down and set the input focus to the clicked element. My suggestion would prevent this; as it would move the focus back to the UI element that had the focus before opening the drop-down)

Comment: @elgonzo Apologies for the confusion, the element that loses focus is placed at the top of the combobox dropdown (so it is only visible when the dropdown is open). Then, if the user moves the mouse over a `ComboBoxItem`, the element at the top loses focus as a `ComboBoxItem` gets it. I can post some example XAML for you if it helps. Strangely, turning `IsEditable` on turns the focus on the `ComboBoxItems` off as well without this issue, but `IsEditable` itself causes a whole range of different issues

Comment: Let me guess, that element at the top is the search/filtering text box?

Comment: @elgonzo It is indeed

Comment: What specifically would be the problems with making the combobox editable? When making the combobox editable, its edit field could itself be used to enter the filter pattern and avoid all the pain with the focus (see here: http://dotbay.blogspot.com/2009/04/building-filtered-combobox-for-wpf.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe it's kind of a hack but it works for me: (XAML Test Project with Framework 4.7.1)

Change your XAML to this:

```
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" x:Name="MyComboBox" DropDownOpened="DropDownWasOpened">
            <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
                </Style>
            </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ComboBox>
```

And in code behind add the handler:

```
    private void DropDownWasOpened(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var selectedItem = MyComboBox.SelectedItem;
        MyComboBox.SelectedItem = null;

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => MyComboBox.SelectedItem = selectedItem));
    }
```

It even has the advantage that the ComboBox opens with the same scroll position as closed.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the answer. This appears to get around the issue without hanging the program. Will award you the bounty in the grace period if there are no more answers that achieve the same but in a more MVVM style

Comment: Apologies for not awarding you the bounty in the grace period. I had a few internet issues that prevented me from doing so

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure how exactly your setup looks like, but I've managed to have a `TextBox` and a `ComboBox` with the former retaining focus while selecting items from the latter. The trick was twofold - make the `ComboBox` not focusable (so it does not steal focus when clicked to open the dropdown), and handle `PreviewGotKeyboardFocus` on `ComboBoxItem` to prevent it from gaining focus on hover as an alternative to setting `Focusable` to `false`, which apparently is the cause of your issue. Here's the code excerpt:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox></TextBox>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Focusable="False">
        <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                <EventSetter Event="PreviewGotKeyboardFocus"
                             Handler="ComboBoxItem_PreviewGotKeyboardFocus" />
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```

And code-behind:

```
private void ComboBoxItem_PreviewGotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is a good way of getting around the keyboard focus issue. I will award you the bounty at the end if no one solves the problem in the question as this may be the closest I get to it.

Answer (score 4):

What you try to achieve is not possible, as far as I could tell by digging into the source code.

When `DropDown` is opened `ComboBox` tries to [navigate](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ComboBox.cs,269) to the `SelectedItem`

Internally [`MakeVisible`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ItemsControl.cs,2705) is called to scroll to `SelectedItem`

The interesting part is here

```
GetFirstItemOnCurrentPage(container, FocusNavigationDirection.Up, out firstElement);
while (firstElement != container)
```

See https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ItemsControl.cs Line 2735,2736

This `while-loop` will never evaluate to `true` when setting `Focusable` to `false`, cause [`GetFirstItemOnCurrentPage`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ItemsControl.cs,2779) will always set `firstElement` to `null`. This will lead to scrolling to the very end and therefore layout processing for a whole bunch of items, in your case too much as this could be handled fast enough, this depends also on your current `SelectedItem` how much items there are left to scroll.

The reason why `GetFirstItemOnCurrentPage` sets `firstElement` always to `null` is because internally [`FindFocusable`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ItemsControl.cs,2592) is called.

```
private object FindFocusable(int startIndex, int direction, out int foundIndex, out FrameworkElement foundContainer)
{
    // HasItems may be wrong when underlying collection does not notify, but this function
    // only cares about what's been generated and is consistent with ItemsControl state.
    if (HasItems)
    {
        int count = Items.Count;
        for (; startIndex >= 0 && startIndex < count; startIndex += direction)
        {
            FrameworkElement container = ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(startIndex) as FrameworkElement;

            // If the UI is non-null it must meet some minimum requirements to consider it for
            // navigation (focusable, enabled).  If it has no UI we can make no judgements about it
            // at this time, so it is navigable.
            if (container == null || Keyboard.IsFocusable(container))
            {
                foundIndex = startIndex;
                foundContainer = container;
                return Items[startIndex];
            }
        }
    }

    foundIndex = -1;
    foundContainer = null;
    return null;
}
```

See https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ItemsControl.cs Line 2592-2618

As you can see `Keyboard.IsFocusable` is called, which in your case is always `false`

Comment: Thank you for the answer and good description of why what I want may not be achievable

Answer (score 4):

First, lets clarify... Your program is not CRASHING (actual run-time erroring out), but hanging (or apparent hang) after you perform a given action.

In fact, it is NOT a problem with the combobox, but the number of items within it.  Yes, you may be using some filtering or searchable context, but the overall hang is the number of elements.

Without changing a thing in your code except the loop of random strings, I dropped the list to 50 and kept increasing double+plus until I could get something more measurable.. 50, 100, 250, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000, etc..

When I drop the count to a reasonable number, it works fine... as soon as I kicked it up to about 1000 entries, the delay was slower, but not hung.  At 5000 entries, slower still, but took about 32 seconds to open the drop-down list... This time is on a Dell Alienware machine i7-2.8Ghz, 16gig.  After the second time the drop-down list opened, subsequent attempts were quick.

Now, with your list of 250,000+ records, it is probably just choking the system with the load of values for subsequent display purposes.

All this being said and it is not a problem with the combobox, it is definitely more of a redesign implementation that you need.  If you can edit your original post (vs just adding comments), you might be able to clarify why you would want the list to have all 250k+ records vs a sub-filtered list.  if sub-filtered, maybe repopulating the list based on the underlying filter would be a better choice.

Another caveat... If I first pick an item near the top of the list, let the combobox close, then click to re-open it, it takes about a minute+ (10k records) before re-opening.  Then if I pick an entry near the bottom of the list, close it and then re-open, it appears quick.  Pick an entry near the top, close it and re-open, it takes long time again.

Obviously over-populating the list is not the way to go and you need to consider alternatives in your UI.

What the problem is, is the reload of the combobox on subsequent attempts to display.  For whatever internal reasons going in, the more records you have in the list, the longer the time to rebuild the display.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for:

```
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Focusable="False" />
            </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
      </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer but I am afraid not. This does not make the `ComboBoxItem` elements unfocusable but rather the `TextBlock` itself which was not what I desire